# Entity Framework SaveChanges throws "Invalid object name" but its generated SQL runs just fine

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

When we run...

```
var dbContext = new MyDbContext();
dbContext.Database.Log = s => Debug.WriteLine(s);

//contactinfo
dbContext.ContactInfo.Attach(model);
dbContext.Entry(model).State = GetBindingModelState(model);
//address
dbContext.Address.Attach(model.Address);
dbContext.Entry(model.Address).State = GetBindingModelState(model);
//save
var result = await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
```

We receive the following error.

> Invalid object name 'dbo.Address'.

This SQL from the `Database.Log`, though, runs without a problem.

```
INSERT [dbo].[Address]([Street], [City], [Province], [PostalCode], [Country])
VALUES (NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL)
SELECT [Id]
FROM [dbo].[Address]
WHERE @@ROWCOUNT > 0 AND [Id] = scope_identity()
```

How can we debug this? What's going on?

- If we comment out the attaching of `ContactInfo`; the error still occurs.
- If we comment out the attaching of `Address`; the error occurs with `Invalid object name 'dbo.ContactInfo'`.
- In both cases, the generate SQL from the `Database.Log` runs just fine.

Comment: You are probably executing the "generated SQL" query in another database or server?

Comment: This appears to be it. I just did a Quick Watch on the DbContext and the connection string is different, because we are running from a unit test. Do you know how to use the original projects conn string?

Comment: It depends on how do you create the *DbContext*

Comment: What do you usually do when unit testing? What do you recommend? I.e. use the same DB, use a different DB and run the migrations on the different DB, other?

Comment: We ended up running the code-first migrations on the other database. That did the trick. `update-database -ConnectionString "Data Source=(localdb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=DefaultConnection;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" -ConnectionProviderName "System.Data.SqlClient"`

Comment: If you are unit testing something different than the database (or the data access layer), you shouldn't connect to the database... Anyway you can configure the connection strings to be on the config files to use different databases for each project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We were executing the "generated SQL" against the live database, whereas the `DbContext` was executing against the test database (thank you thepirat000). This occurred because we were running the  `DbContext` from a unit test. The fix was to run our code-first migration on the test database.